# Unable to print Elements in Generic stack in Java

Tags: class

i have this code of a generic implementation of stacks in java.
I have used array implementation with some fixed size 2000

```
public class Stack_using_Array<E> {
    int N;
    int i; //starting index
    private E arr[];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Stack_using_Array(int N){
        arr=(E[]) new Object[N];
        i=0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    void push(E object ) throws FullStackException{
        if(i==N-1){
            throw new FullStackException("stack is full"); 
        }
        arr[i]=(E) new Object();
        arr[i]=object;
        i++;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E pop() throws FullStackException{
        if(i==0){
            throw new FullStackException("stack is empty");
        }
        arr[i]=(E) new Object();
        E ob=arr[i];
        arr[i]=null;
        i--;
        return ob;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String s=""+arr[i];
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        Stack_using_Array<Integer> stack= new Stack_using_Array<Integer>();
        try{
            stack.push(67);
            stack.push(90);
            stack.push(78);
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        } catch (FullStackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

But when i try to print them, the outcome comes like

```
java.lang.Object@15db9742
java.lang.Object@6d06d69c
java.lang.Object@7852e922
```

it is the address of the object maybe. I want to print the Integers.please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is in `pop()` method, remove this line, there is no need to instantiate a new value here:

```
arr[i]=(E) new Object();
```

and also change the other two lines to manage index and array position, it's not the same:

```
E ob = arr[i-1];
arr[i-1] = null;
```

Second problem: remove the toString method, it's completly wrong and can cause unwanted exceptions.